# Mysql access denied error 1045 with Django app

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've been creating a webapp using Django and Mysql database, and it was working fine for a few months, but lately it's been acting up. I have a Linkedin auth system, which used to work on localhost, but now throws a 1045 "access denied" error for 'root'@'localhost' (using password: "YES"). I can't access the database at all.

Here are some things I've tried, based on other StackOverflow answers:

Logged in as mysql -u root -p, did:

```
    grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'pass' with grant option;
```

Didn't work, so I tried this:

```
    grant all privileges on *.* to <user>@localhost identified by 'pass' with grant option;
```

Also didn't work, tried this:

```
    grant all privileges on *.* to ''@'localhost' identified by 'pass' with grant option;
```

None of these solve the problem. It's not just a Linkedin auth problem, the problem stems from the fact that the database no longer recognizes 'root'@'localhost' for some reason, because when I try to access the database directly via a Python shell, I get the same error.

Comment: If you add a grant to `root@'%'`, i.e. root@anyhost, would that help? Note that this potentially allows remote root access as well, so if that helps, this needs to be refined further to pin-point the issue.

Comment: No, that's still the same error, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, and if you try logging in not as `mysql -u root -p`, but as `mysql -u root -h localhost --protocol=tcp -p`, which actually forces the client to use TCP, rather than file socket? Cause file socket doesn't really do any hostname resolving.

Comment: No that didn't work either. Still get the error for 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: Aha, so well, the issue is not in your framework. Did you upgrade your MySQL installation by any chance lately? If so, did you run http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html ?

Comment: I have not upgraded my Mysql Installation at all since installing last May.